# How to reference to the standard ActorSystem of play framework 2?

Tags: scala, playframework, akka, playframework-2.3

I wish to use the scheduler of akka, the examples are saying:

```
system.scheduler.scheduleOnce()
```

but there is no real information where the "system" should come from. The documentation is a little bit superficial and there was a lot of change (akka moved out of core scala).

If I write

```
val system = akka.actor.ActorSystem("system")
```

I will have a ActorSystem, but it will be a new independent ActorSystem with around 8 new threads. I think, that this is an overkill for a small scheduler and not really recommended.

How can I just re-use the existing system of play framework 2 ?
Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To get hands on the default actor system defined by Play you have to import the `play.api.libs.concurrent.Akka` [helper](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.8/ScalaAkka#The-application-actor-system).

`Akka.system` will be a reference to the default actor system, and then you can do everything with it as you would do with an actor system created by yourself:

```
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Akka

val myActor = Akka.system.actorOf(Props[MyActor], name = "myactor")
Akka.system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(...)
```

**update**:
The above static methods became deprecated in Play 2.5 and was removed in 2.6, so now you have to [use dependency injection](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/Migration26#Akka-deprecated-methods-removed).

In Scala:

```
class MyComponent @Inject() (system: ActorSystem) {

}
```

In Java:

```
public class MyComponent {

    private final ActorSystem system;

    @Inject
    public MyComponent(ActorSystem system) {
        this.system = system;
    }
}
```

Comment: can we use `context.system()` as well?

Comment: yes, but that works only from inside an already existing actor

Comment: Hi, Thanks could please look into this one. I have been trying hard on this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42963476/cannot-use-a-method-returning-play-mvc-websocket-as-a-handler-for-requests-in-pl#42963476

Comment: what is the way to get the reference of `system` in `play 2.6`? `Akka.system` and `context.system()` doesn't work in `2.6`

Comment: @ManuChadha I updated the answer with the content of https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/Migration26#Akka-deprecated-methods-removed

Answer (score 1):

When you use `play.api.libs.concurrent.Akka` you are using the actor system created by play. In fact that is the way encouraged.
You can read that in the [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.8/ScalaAkka).

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer and the link. I was looking on https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ThreadPools and http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.4/scala/dispatchers.html and looking for "system".